# MATLAB - how do I (elegantly) interpolate a matrix?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Suppose I have a cell array with 3 elements; the first and third cells are matrices, while the second is empty:

```
>> P
P = 
  [3x8 double]    []    [3x8 double]
```

I can fill in the second matrix by interpolating for every individual element in the matrix, but surely there must be a way to do this in one shot?

**EDIT**: An average would certainly work for P. But suppose I have something like

```
>> Q
Q = [3x8 double]    [3x8 double]     [3x8 double]    []    []    [3x8 double]
```

So given my four known matrices, I could use a fancier interpolation (like spline) to fill in the missing matrices.

Comment: If the elements at (1,1) in the first and third cells were 1 and 2, respectively, are you wanting to average them so (1,1) in the second cell would be 1.5?  Or do you mean something fancier by `interpolate`?

Comment: @tmpearce An average would certainly do. There will be times when the data in the matrices don't necessarily scale linearly, and I may have other matrices to pull from. I can edit the question to show a more general case.

Comment: One more question: Would 1-d interpolation of each position in the matrices be the desired result?  I.e. looking at all (1,1)s would be all that was required to determine the missing values in (1,1) index?

Comment: @tmpearce - yes, but was hoping for a more "elegant" (i.e., loopless) solution

Comment: I know... but that information is useful for figuring out which loopless way of doing what you want :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform all the interpolation in a single function call to INTERP1, but it requires setting the data into the desired shape, then back once done:

```
%# cell array of matrices (some are missing)
sz = [3 8];         %# all of same size
Q = {ones(sz), [], 3*ones(sz), [], [], 6*ones(sz)};

%# indices of missing matrices
idx = ~cellfun(@isempty,Q);
x = 1:numel(Q);

%# merge cells into a multidimensional matrix, call INTERP1, then divide back
QQ = Q(idx);
QQ = permute(cat(3,QQ{:}), [3 1 2]);
QQ = interp1(x(idx), QQ, x);            %# one call to interpolation function
QQ = reshape(num2cell(permute(QQ, [2 3 1]), [1 2]), 1,[]);
```

Just keep in mind that vectorization sometimes comes at the cost of readability...

Comment: I only have to do this one time to some data that I've already generated. The plan is to never have to generate this data again, so hopefully I'm the only one who ever has to read that code.. :)

Comment: @DangKhoa: well, you were warned :)

Comment: could this be tweaked to deal with extrapolation as well? So if the first matrix is empty but the rest are okay, it could fill in that data too. I realize extrapolation isn't the most stable of operations but my data should be nearly linear.

Comment: @DangKhoa: easy, just specify the [`'extrap'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html#f86-998802) option in the INTERP1 call: `QQ = interp1(x(idx), QQ, x, 'linear', 'extrap');`

Comment: holy crap, i didn't know that was a thing. nice.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work for your toy case:

```
l = length(P{1}(:)); m = size(P{1}, 1); n = size(P{1}, 2);
myfun = @(x) interp1([1 3], [P{1}(x) P{3}(x)], 2)
P{2} = reshape(arrayfun(myfun, 1:l), m, n);
```

More general code (**verified!!**) that will work in general. You can specify which type of interpolation to use in the one interp1 call:

```
[m, n] = size(P{1}); l = m*n;
avbl = find(not(cellfun('isempty', P)));
missing = find(cellfun('isempty', P));

extractor = @(k) cellfun(@(x, k) x(k), {P{avbl}}, cellmat(1, length(avbl), 1, 1, k))
myfun = @(x) interp1(avbl, extractor(x), missing)
intermediate = reshape(arrayfun(myfun, 1:l, 'UniformOutput', false), m, n);
ext2 = @(k) cellfun(@(p) p(k), intermediate);
P(missing) = arrayfun(ext2, 1:length(missing), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Let me know if you want me to explain some of the parts. It's basically just calling cellfun a few times and then reshaping the output.

Comment: I'm joking, of course... my degree was in ECE, and I learned MATLAB, I'm just much more used to ALGOL-60/C style languages

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
     p{2} = (p{1} + p{3}) / 2;  % note the curly braces
```

?